# Gcloud deploy is not deploying a folder

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am servicing a system.
An old App Engine tool was used to deploy, but it is now obsolete and I need to use the gcloud command line.

However, gcloud is ignoring one system folder and deploying all others.

One big reason this must be happening is because they developed this system based on node_modules and didn't build the code before uploading. In short, I need the node_modules folder for the code to execute.

I already disabled .gcloudignore, but there have been no changes.

Source folder structure:

[image]

Folder Structure in App Engine:

[image]

I ran the --verbosity = info code on my gcloud deploy and it appeared that they were ignoring it:

[image]

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: 2.6
- name: lxml
  version: 2.3
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: app/static
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: manage.app
  secure: always

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Comment: glcoudignore may prevent the upload of the node_modules/ directory If you have already specified it in the .gcloudignore. Please check this link [1].

Could you provide the following information to further understand the issue:

- Did you use "gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled false"[2] to disable gcloudignore?

If not, can you provide the steps you took to disable it?

  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore#EXAMPLES
  [2]: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore#DESCRIPTION

Comment: - What exact command did you use to deploy your app?

- Before you try to deploy, please try the following command to check which files will be uploaded and let me know if the node_modules file is one of them.

gcloud meta list-files-for-upload 

If the file is present in the output of the command, could you try to deploy them and see if all files get deployed. This could help to pinpoint the issue.

- Have you ever tried to remove the gcloudignore command from your file and try to deploy your app?.

Comment: @LetitiaFatima  Please don't post images of text, instead copy-paste the text in your post and format it accordingly. Thx.

Comment: Hi @Katayoon, I used "gcloud config set gcloudignore / enabled false" to disable .gcloudignore.
And to deploy, I used "gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version = 19 --project = id_project"

Comment: We were able to reproduce the issue in Python 2.7, on a Linux environment by creating a soft link to a file in the folder. Having a soft link in the folder, it prevents the whole folder from being deployed. When we removed the file’s soft link, the folder was uploaded successfully and the issue was resolved. Looking into the internal reports, we can see this issue is already reported and is fixed for Python 3. Note that Python 2.7 is not being supported by GCP anymore[1]. So, we highly recommend migrating to Python 3.7.

Comment: Let me know if this is the case so that we will post it as an answer.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset/#python-2-support-status

Answer (score 0):

By default, flask use a "templates" folder to contain all your template files(any plain-text file, but usually .html or some kind of template language such as jinja2 ) & a "static" folder to contain all your static files(i.e. .js .css and your images).

So ideally you should not use /static [folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=static#flask.Flask.static_folder)

you will need to update app.yaml to include handler static_dir: static

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest

# [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
# [END handlers]
```

The best way to use is

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='')
```

Comment: Hello, this part already exists in my code. I will update the question with this.

Comment: I renamed the static folder static_test and the folder was deployed. However, it still didn't work because the name was no longer found by the code. I renamed it to app.yaml and the folder disappeared again after deployment with the modifications to app.yaml

Comment: @LeticiaFatima, have you tried renaming anything other than static in it ?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it static_new and did not update app.yaml with the new name and gcloud deployed the folder. So I updated app.yaml with the new name static_new and the folder disappeared again from the app engine project.

Comment: @LeticiaFatima, I mean change the folder name anything other than static*

Comment: I changed the folder name to frontend and it resulted in the same thing, when I update the folder name in app.yaml, the folder disappears from the app engine again

Comment: Did you try deploying again with different app engine service name and updating .gcloudignore file ?

Comment: I deployed to another app engine project and changed gcloudignore.
In gcloudignore,I forced it to deploy the static folder and ignore gitignore (I think this may also be blocking the folder), but the folder still doesn't appear in the structure.

Comment: Can you please share the .gcloudignore and .gitignore file ?